# PostGIS and connection to QGIS issue?

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

I have a problem with PostGIS and a connection to QGIS. I successfully connected to a database on a server but when I try to add a PostGIS Table, I am getting warning symbols next to all my tables. I have permission to all the tables and
I am using the latest version of QGIS.

Any hints?

[image]

Comment: what happens if you manually change the srid, featureid and geometry_type values to the right of the table name? (You may need to scroll to see them). i think qgis relies on the postgis geometry_columns table to pre-populate these, but some tools don't set these up so you have to do this manually.

Comment: Better use the db manager once your connexion is set as you will see all of your tables (non geometric one too) and you just have to drag them to the toc. You will not have to select manually the fields mentioned by @StevenKay.